# React Navigation : Current screen also updates when pushing same screen in stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

When i push `Posts` screen in a stack navigator with `query` prop, prev screen also updates and all data are same in all screen.

```js
navigation.dispatch(StackActions.push('Posts', { query: { keyword: 'iphone' } }))
```

or

```js
navigation.push('Posts', { query: { keyword: 'iphone' } })
```

Any solutions?

---

`React Native: 0.71.x`
`React navigation : ^6.x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of `@tanstack/react-query@4.^` library i used in my app with `react-navigation@6.^`, when i push `Posts` screen, prev screen also changed every time i push. i don't know why but now i use react-native fetch and its works fine.